# Python: How to retrieve a reference to self object from within generator?

Tags: python, generator

I have some generator. Can I access the generator object from within itself?

This is not unlike `self` in a class instance.

```py
def generator():
   yield 1
   yield 2
   # how to access ``a`` here?

a = generator()
```

Of course I can pass `a` as an argument. Let's suppose I cannot do that. Is there another way?

Comment: why? what do you think this would help to achieve?

Comment: I mean, if you pass ‘a’ to the class, it would do the exact same thing by doing it with ‘self’.

Comment: @DeepSpace I assume he has some variable defined in the generator function which are saved when iterating over the generator. He probably is trying to modify those variables from outside the generator function to achieve different yield results during iteration.

Comment: @TinNguyen sounds like a bad idea, even if it's possible to hack somehow

Comment: You can define a and pass it to a setter method

Comment: I agree. But I think he has a fundamental understanding problem what `self` is. Nagyl: the first parameter of a function in a class is the instance of the class. It is vastly different from a passed parameter. They are not the exact same thing.

Comment: Not arguing it is a bad idea. It breaks all the abstraction layers. BTW, I have no application in mind. I was just wondering: the generator object that corresponds to the current execution of the generator frame is unique, so I'd have expected Python to provide a mechanism for accessing it.

Comment: @TinNguyen no, from within a method `self` is in no different than any other argument. Upon definition of the class, the constructor (not `__init__`!) binds the methods to the class instance. The bound method just wraps the original function, passing the reference to the instance as the first argument. But let's not argue about this :)